Adding/deleting rows across sheets while keeping data in order
first time asking for advice here. I've tried searching the internet for a solution but haven't been able to find anything similar enough to what I am trying to do to work.
The problem:
I generate training documents using excel, where we have to capture information in one format, that is then later expanded upon in later spreadsheets. Currently we do everything manually or using = and referencing the original sheet. But this has the issue that, as soon as we go back to the original, or a sheet later down the line and change something, it isn't reflected across those sheets. I've tried to create examples of data below.
Sheet 1 is the first sheet we work with, were we simply generate a numbered hierarchy against the 'tasks' we identify for the role we will be training. Sometimes there is a third column for notes.
What we then do, is 'copy' the information in Sheet 1 to Sheet 2, normally using the =data formula, to 'copy' it across.
Once that information is in Sheet 2, we then add the additional columns where we capture Knowledge and Skills required for each task/subtask listed. We also do this for further sheets, where we take the information from Sheet 1 to generate other tables, wanting to keep the original information from Sheet 1, but adding additional columns to conduct other work.
The issue, is that if we realise down the line, that maybe we missed sub task 1.3. If we go back to Sheet 1 and add it in. While we could update the 'copied' list (through =) to Sheet 2 and 3 etc. any information already in the sheet is then not 'linked' to the right task. (Unless I am doing something wrong).
The question:
Is there a way to be able to add in a row in Sheet 1, and have that row appear with the new information added across all other sheets (with columns for knowledge and skill obviously empty), and more importantly, also if I was to delete a row?
I hope my question makes some sense. Again, first time asking for excel advice, so apologies if I haven't explained it very well.
SHEET 1: Task data



Number
Task description




1
Top level task


1.1
Sub task


1.2
Sub task


2
New top level task



SHEET 2: Task KSA analysis



Number
Task description
Knowledge required
Skill required




1
Top level task
Details of knowledge for Task 1
Details of skills for Task 1


1.1
Sub task
Details of knowledge for sub task
Details of skills for sub task


1.2
Sub task
Details of knowledge for sub task
Details of skills for sub task


2
New top level task
Details of knowledge for Task 2
Details of skills for Task 2



I saw something about Excel Power Query, which did show me how to make a 'table' which I did with the number column, and add an index column, but the issue was that it only seemed to add a new 'row' second from the bottom of my table, and didn't move any information I had to the right of the table to keep it 'linked' to the right task.
I also tried something with VLOOKUP that someone recommended, but couldn't get it to work with the whole adding in a new row anywhere in the table and having data shift appropriately.

I thought PowerQuery would be the way to go, but after I explored that a bit, I think I understand your issue:  Inserting a row in table "Task Data" causes the data in the additional columns on Sheet 2 to come out of sorts.  Does that sound accurate?  Would it make sense to have a helper table that is the Number column, Knowledge required, and Skill required, then merging that with Task Data to give the KSA analysis?  You'll be able to see gaps that way to know if data is missing.

This is a fantastic solution that should work for your case: https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/.
